# XCOPY Batch File for all users

Tags: batch-file, command-line, xcopy

I need a batch file to do the following:

**XCopy From:** 
C:\Folder1

**To Destination:**

C:\IT\userfolders\USER-**A**\AppData\

C:\IT\userfolders\USER-**B**\AppData\

C:\IT\userfolders\USER-**C**\AppData\

etc
etc
etc

The name "User-A" represents the username for each person and there are 100's of users, is there a command I can use for "C:\IT\userfolders**ALL FOLDERS**\AppData\

Many Thanks

Answer (score 0):

```
for /f "delims=" %%a in ('dir /b /ad "C:\IT\userfolders" ') do (
 ECHO(xcopy c:\folder1" "C:\IT\userfolders\%%a\AppData\"
)
```

When you're happy this works, change `ECHO(xcopy` to `xcopy` to actually do the copy.

This is presumed to be a line in a batch file. If you are entering diretly from the prompt, reduce `%%a` to `%a` throughout.